# 500: Internal Server Error Spotify python Auth Code flow trying to redirect to login and get token

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, spotify

I am using [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) documentation to get the user to login and return me code and state. However, when I run my app It gives me a 500 error.

This is my app.py

```
import flask
import SpotifyOAuth

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flask.render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/login')
def accessSpotify():
    SpotifyOAuth.RedirectTologin(redirect_uri='https://localhost:7001/authorized')

@app.route('/authorized')
def SP_redirect_uri():
    return "spotify connected"

def main():
    print("nothin")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True,port=7001)
```

and this is my SpotifyOAuth.py

```
import requests

def RedirectTologin(redirect_uri="https://localhost:7001/authorized"):
    token_uri="https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
    method="GET"
    params={
        "client_id" : '<id>',
        "response_type" : 'code',
        "redirect_uri" : redirect_uri,
        "scope" : 'user-read-email'
    }
    client_secret='<secret>'
    r = requests.get(token_uri,params=params)
    print(r)

if __name__=='__main__':
    RedirectTologin()
```

I know my RedirectTLogin() is working because when I print r it gives me response code 200. Not sure where I am going wrong in app.py

Here is my index.html for reference

```
<html>
<body>
 <div>
    <div id="login">
     <h1>First, log in to spotify</h1>
     <a href="/login">Log in</a>
    </div>
    <div id="loggedin">
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone see any issue? I don't have much experience working with APIs

Answer (score 0):

Flask routes need to return something: a rendered template, a redirect, plain text with a status code, etc.

To fix your issue you need to add `return`s to `index()` and `accessSpotify()` as follows:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.render_template("index.html")
```

```py
@app.route('/login')
def accessSpotify():
    SpotifyOAuth.RedirectTologin(redirect_uri='https://localhost:7001/authorized')

    return flask.redirect(url_for('SP_redirect_uri'))
```